# Logon failed, "no logon server" Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking

I joined Ubuntu to a Windows domain but if disconnect the ethernet cable I cannot log on with domain users. I am presented with the error message:

```
no logon server
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty straightforward. Your system has no servers to verify the user (which is no surprise since you cut the connection).

I assume you are using samba and winbind. The following entry the `smb.conf` should do the trick

```
winbind offline logon = yes
```

see e.g. this [samba wiki article](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/PAM_Offline_Authentication)

Comment: after add this command to smb.conf , when disconnect the Ethernet cable the message incorrect password shown , please your help